# Drupal7 Using Geoip Module by entering zipcode can i get the location of Country?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, geoip

I'm Using Drupal7 Geoip module for getting the customer location dynamically according to the users_ip address.

But as per our requirement, we need to get location of the country by if customers enter the zipcode(and filter in our options).

Is there any option(GNU API) or contributed module is available to get the location of the country by entering the zipcodes of any country dynamically.

Some other suggestions also welcome....

Answer (score 0):

We have [Postal Code](https://www.drupal.org/project/postal_code) and [Postal Code validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/postal_code_validation) modules which could help you if you want to get country by Zip Code you can use these modules functions. hope those be a clue to find your solution.